# Kendo UI Mobile - Can't open external links

Tags: kendo-ui

How can i open external links using Kendo UI Mobile 2012.3.1114.

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li><a href="tel:1-555-555-5555" data-rel="external">tel:1-555-555-5555</a></li>
    <li><a href="mailto:test@test.com" data-rel="external">mailto:test@test.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="geo:0,0?q=google" data-rel="external">geo:0,0?q=google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://google.com/" data-rel="external">http://google.com/</a></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/macwebdev/uQmcD/

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

HTML5 attribute data-rel="external" should work, or use Javascript/jQuery to change url.

Kendo HTML5 Example:

```
<a href="http://kendoui.com/" data-rel="external">Visit KendoUI</a>
```

More Info:
http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/application#linking-to-external-pages

Javascript/jQuery Example:

```
$("body").on("click",'a[data-rel="external"]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/uQmcD/4/

Comment: window.location.href = $(this).attr("href"); doesn't work on iOS.  You need to use window.open( yourUrl );

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading a newer version of Kendo Mobile. There was a bug which manifested itself in a similar way.

Comment: This bug has not been addressed in the latest internal build (2012.3.1121).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding target="_blank" to your links.

PS: It works with the 2012-versions of Kendo, but not with the recent version together with newest PhoneGap.